# Laravel - Use validation rule inside Custom Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am writing a custom validation rule on Laravel 4. However, I am looking forward to use the existing validation rules ( example : exists, email, min etc. ) inside it. I am not sure how to do this, and I am guessing using Validator::make is not really the right way. My code is below:

```
    Validator::extend('check_fulfilled',function($attribute,$value,$parameters){
        $movieidfield = Input::get('movieid');
                if(     empty($movieidfield )    ) return false;
                    // Here I would like to test $movieidfield 
                    //with exists and min validation rules 
    });
```

It would be really great if someone can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Presumably you could instantiate your own validator inside that function and use that to test the value at hand?

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that?

Comment: Juts the normal way you'd use a validator as if in a controller. `$v = Validator::make()`, etc.

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri answered?

Answer (score 0):

[Validation rules are composable](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules).

A custom validation rule like yours shouldn't need to get values from the Input parameter bag. [`Validator` class already takes care of that](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L210).

```
Validator::extend('check_fulfilled', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    return !empty($value);
});
```

For example, to use your custom validation rule with other existing rules you could write when instantiating your `Validator` instance:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, array(
     'movieid' => 'check_fulfilled|email',
));
```

> Unless you know what you are doing should you inline validation rules.

To achieve that, you could resolve `Validator` singleton in the app service container that is registered there by the [ValidationServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationServiceProvider.php#L23).

```
Validator::extend('check_fulfilled', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
    if (empty($movieidfield)) return false;
    $v = App::make('validator');

    return $v->validateExists($attribute, $value, $parameters) 
           && $v->validateEmail($attribute, $value);
});
```

Note that the `$parameters` array would need to hold values for the inlined validation rules.

Refer to signature of the validation methods to understand what arguments to passed.

[`Validator::validateExists($attribute, $value, $parameters)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L713)

[`Validator::validateEmail($attribute, $value)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L791)

[`Validator::validateMin($attribute, $value, $parameters)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.0.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L568)