# Laravel: how to call custom Validator inside the rules() function of a custom FormRequest class?

Tags: laravel, validation

Looking at the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation I kinda understand how you can make a custom Validator and call it as an object within a controller function.

I am familiar with using custom FormRequests, but it's not clear to me how to call a custom Validation within the `rules()` function of a custom FormRequest class instead.

For example if I want to use the following example from the documentation:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
 
Validator::make($data, [
    'zones' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['first-zone', 'second-zone']),
    ],
]);
```

Where do I have to define the above and how can I then get to the point where I can call it like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class TestRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'zone' => 'zones', // Using the custom Validator
        ];
    }
}
```

There is this example that sort of explains a little bit [Laravel - Use validation rule inside Custom Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444292/laravel-use-validation-rule-inside-custom-validation) but it doesn't actually say how to then use it withing the `rules()` function

There is also documentation on how to create a custom Rule (which I'm supposing is a required step unless the custom role can be defined within the FormRequest).

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Rules;
 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\InvokableRule;
 
class Uppercase implements InvokableRule
{
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  \Closure  $fail
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($attribute, $value, $fail)
    {
        if (strtoupper($value) !== $value) {
            $fail('The :attribute must be uppercase.');
        }
    }
}
```

But the only example available on how to call it is as a validation object, not as a rule inside a FormRequest (unless I misunderstand), so that isn't helpful for my intentions.

```
use App\Rules\Uppercase;
 
$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', 'string', new Uppercase],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already found the way how to use the your custom validator in your FormRequest. At method rules, just use it like 'New Uppercase' in array. So the example will be like below (* I add example zone is required and Uppercase):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'zone' => ['required', new Uppercase]
    ];
}
```

Dont forget to import your custom validator class.